# Modifying a Location header with nginx proxy_pass

Tags: regex, nginx, header, url-rewriting, proxypass

I have an nginx `proxy_pass` setup to pass every request on `/api` through to a backend Tomcat REST service. This service in some cases returns a `Location` header which varies according to the type of request, e.g., `Location: http://foo.bar/baz/api/search/1234567` -- the `baz` part is due to it being hosted on Tomcat.

My current configuration rewrites the `foo.bar` host name correctly, but leaves the `baz` part intact. I'd like to strip this, but the proxy_pass options seem to be limited to clearing or setting a new value for the header.

Is there a way to modify headers dynamically before being passed on to the client, using a regex substitute, for instance? This is my nginx configuration:

```
location /api {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_buffers           32 4k;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://foo.bar:8080/baz/api;
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may be able to use regexp to modify it but a better way is to use a proxy redirect:

```
proxy_redirect http://foo.bar/baz/ /;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Any Location headers for `foo.bar/baz/` will go to `/`

If you just want to redirect `/baz/api`, that'll work too.

If any redirects are also adding the port, you'll need to add `http://foo.bar:8080/baz/` as well (separate redirect).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not so much interested in redirecting (which is working fine), but in modifying the `Location` header which is returned as a server response. The API returns a `Location` header containing the URL where the client is supposed fetch the results of its previous query. This is now pointing to a faulty location because the server doesn't know it's being proxied.

Comment: proxy_redirect modifies the Location header... That's the purpose of it. Take a look at the nginx docs (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect) :)

Comment: Oh, I see! That did indeed do it. Thank you! (Although I do think `redirect` isn't the best name for what it actually does)

Comment: Agreed! I think proxy_rewrite or something like that would make so much more sense lol

Comment: @ChelseaUrquhart How do I modify only certain part of the URL and not the whole URL?