# If X- custom header is no longer supported (deprecated by IETF) how do we return custom headers?

Tags: api, rest, http-headers, custom-headers

According to this thread:

[Custom HTTP headers : naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions)

And the IETF link, using X- headers is no longer supported. However, I still see APIs that use them for responses. I've also recently done some configuration with nginx and it uses a few uses of X- headers. For example another post here:

[Modifying a Location header with nginx proxy_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568452/modifying-a-location-header-with-nginx-proxy-pass)

shows the use of X-Forwarded-For and a few others.

So.. via the IETF deprecation, is all use of any X- header basically being told to no longer use it? Or are their cases where it's allowed?

If they are no longer allowed, then do we return headers without the X- in it?

I ask because my REST API is returning login tokens (session tokens really) via x-auth-token:  and consumers of my API would look for that header to get the token. I've seen many other APIs out there use a similar manner to provide oauth or other tokens.

I just want some sort of definitive understanding if x- is bad but we can still return custom headers without the x- (so in my case it would just be a response header named auth-token)?

Thanks.

Comment: RFC 6648 is worded as "SHOULD NOT", meaning you shouldn't do it, but it's not forbidden.

Comment: Ok.. but in the first thread they also indicate that using X- is bad so use good names.. does that mean using custom headers is fine, just don't use X- in the name of the header?

Comment: it says to use good names, with the understanding that there's no guarantee a future revision of the standards won't use that name for itself. e.g. a header called "MICROSOFT_FOO_BAR_BAZ" probably won't get co-opted into the standard, but "FOO_BAR_BAZ" might, if whatever functionality it's for becomes widespread.