# Redirect/rewrite nginx location to .sock file without prefix

Tags: sockets, nginx, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

I have one server that has several APIs running on it. One of them is `users-DB` The following gets down to gunicorn just fine:

```
location /usersDB/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/projects/UsersDB-api/app.sock;
}
```

Except when I try to access the usersDB API's /helloWorld route, and look in the logs at gunicorn.err I see:

```
GET /usersDB/helloWorld
```

I was hoping to see:

```
GET /helloWorld
```

Of course, gunicorn returns 404s and that is what I see in my browser. I've tried rewrite rules:

```
location /usersDB/ {
    rewrite /usersDB/(.*) /$1 last;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/projects/UsersDB-api/app.sock;
}
```

But the above results in the requests making their way to `/var/www/htmlhelloWorld` instead of app.sock.

I know that if you use a url for the proxy_pass you just add a [trailing `/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311241/1758759), but I'm not sure what to do in the case of a sock file.

How do I get rid of the `/usersDB/` suffix that is now included on all routes in nginx?

Comment: Also, your `rewrite` would work if you used `break`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a separating `:`. For example:

```
proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/projects/UsersDB-api/app.sock:/;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.